# Deciding complexity class of a TM s.t M(0) = accept

Tags: time-complexity

Below is a sample of 2 homework TM where Im not sure what complexity class they fit in. Also have to decide the complexity class of the complement. These 2 in particular confuse me because I got a different answer so I feel I may be missing something:

S = { : M is a TM s.t. M(0) = accept} U = { : M is a TM s.t. M(0)[20000] = accept}

The options are P, NP, coNP, EXP, Decidable, Recognizable, lang (all strings).

S: I read this as 'M checks if the input is 0, if yes accept'. My first instinct is that S is in P as it simply checks the if the input is 0 which is a single operation, so I would say it can be solved in polynomial time. Someone else decided RE for S and lang for S complement respectively, which I just dont understand if correct.

U: I read this same as S, but runs (to a maximum of?) 2000 steps. I'd also place this in P for both U and its complement. Other answer is P as well but I don't see how the addendum of 2000 makes a difference.

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: For both $S$ and $U$, the input is an (encoding of) Turing machine, do you understand this?

Comment: S is obviously undecidable by Rice's theorem. Whether S is recognizable or not: try building a recognizer for S or complement(S).